# change ksh shell path in linux

Tags: linux

present ksh path in linux is as below

```
-bash-4.1$ which ksh
/bin/ksh

-bash-4.1$ uname
Linux
-bash-4.1$ uname -i
x86_64
```

i want to change this path to /usr/bin/ksh.

could you help me in this?

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to do this? both /bin and /usr/bin are usually part of $PATH.

Comment: all programs of my application is in /usr/bin/ksh path only.

Comment: This will make the programs using `/bin/ksh` not functioning..

Comment: @heemayl no problem, i wont use /bin/ksh

Comment: @Asif; but system commands may use `/bin/ksh`. So you can't just remove it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to define a link, e.g.:

```
ln -s /bin/ksh /usr/bin/ksh
```

You need `root` permission to do that; so invoke the command with `sudo` as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
ln -s /bin/ksh /usr/bin/ksh
```

P.S.

```
ln -s /bin/ksh /usr/bin
```

will work fine as ln command replicate the filename (basename) if second argument is directory